# MariaDB type error when setting session variable

Tags: mysql, session, mariadb, system-variable

why do the following queries work on Maria DB (10.1.9)...

- `SET SESSION wait_timeout = 28000;`
- `SET SESSION wait_timeout = @@wait_timeout;`
- `SELECT GREATEST(28000, @@wait_timeout);`

... but that one not?

- `SET SESSION wait_timeout = GREATEST(28000, @@wait_timeout)`

It throws a type error:

`` #1232 - Incorrect argument type to variable 'wait_timeout` ``

Allthough this error can be resolved by replacing `@wait_timeout` with `CAST(@@wait_timeout AS INT)` or `CONVERT(@@wait_timeout, SIGNED)` (the latter works on MySQL as well) to the query I wonder why the second and third query work.

**What's going on here?** It can't be the *GREATEST* operation because query 3 works and it can't be a differing variable type because the (implicit) conversion would fail in query 2 (it should have the same type anyhow). The same thing happens with other system variables as well.

By the way: The same query works under MySQL (tried it in a SQLfiddle with MySQL version 5.6) so this is an inconsistency between MariaDB and MySQL.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: for kicks, try assigning to some other system var , e.g. `set session some_var_thats_irrelevant=greatest(...)` so you can tell WHICH of the two wait_timeouts the error message is talking about.

Comment: @MarcB good point - ok let's try: "SET SESSION interactive_timeout = GREATEST(28000, @@wait_timeout)" results in "#1232 - Incorrect argument type to variable 'interactive_timeout'"

Comment: further test: `set foo=greatest(2800, @@wait_timeout)`, see if it's something specific about setting session vars, or just a var setting bug in general. could be mariadb's got a regression that barfs on the expression being on the RHS of an assignment

Comment: Mhh.. That one does work: ``set @foo=greatest(2800, @@wait_timeout)``

Comment: I'd go file it as a bug against mariadb.

Comment: Thanks for your support so far. I did file a bug and will report if there are any news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some have guessed correctly: it's a bug (now confirmed) that was introduced recently.

For more details have a look at the mariadb issue tracker:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-9516

#### Update (2016-03-21)

Regarding the bugtracker the problem seems fixed in 10.1.13.